# Find an $SO(3)$-equivariant continuous function from $(\mathbb{R}^3)^n$ to $SO(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, group-theory

If I take $R$ in $SO(3)$ and $x$ in $(\mathbb{R}^3)^n$, ($x$ can be written as $(x_1, ... x_i, ..., x_n)$, with the $x_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

I define $Rx$ = $(Rx_1,..., Rx_i,..., Rx_n)$

I want to find a continuous $f:(\mathbb{R}^3)^n\rightarrow SO(3)$ verifying $f(Rx)$ = $Rf(x)$, if so it is said to be $SO(3)$-equivariant.

I had an idea, but it happened to not be continuous:

Let $V = \sum_i x_i x_i^T\in\mathbb{R}^{3*3}$

$V$ is a real-symmetric matrix (it's even positive semi-definite) hence it can be diagonalised in an orthonormal basis, let $Q=[v_1, v_2, v_3]$ the matrix of eigenvectors ranked by ascending orders of eigenvalues. $f(x)=Q$ verifies the $SO(3)$-equivariance. Though it can be seen that it is not continuous since for eigenvalue $\lambda_i\leftarrow\lambda_i + \epsilon > \lambda_{i+1}$ the columns $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ in $Q$ switch.

EDIT: I forgot to contextualize the problem to my need. You can suppose the points $x$ are sampled with a gaussian distribution. And you can quotient your space by the null probability subspaces where things get out of control (having equal eigenvalues, $x=0$ etc...)

On my idea you can choose between $v_i$ and $-v_i$ by forcing the first non-null coordinate to be positive.

Comment: Your $f$ is not well-defined -- you can flip the sign on two of the eigenvectors.  Moreover, it doesn't work for eigenvalue multiplicity $>1$.

Comment: Anyway, no such $f$ could exist (continuous or not), by considering where you send $(0,0,\dots,0)\in(\mathbb{R}^3)^n$.

Comment: @user10354138 ok sorry I forgot to contextualize the problem to my need. You can suppose the point $x$ are sampled with a gaussian distribution. And you can quotient your space by the null probability subspaces where things get out of control (having equal eigen values, x=0 etc...) also for the not well defined you can trick by taking the first non-null coordinate of the eigen-vector positive, which allows you to choose between vi and -vi.